# 2012 Jeep Patriot CVT Transmission possibly failing

Tags: noise, jeep, cvt-transmission, patriot

I have a CVT in my Jeep Patriot. Within the last 4k miles, I have replaced the fluid with mopar cvtf-4 & replaced both filters. I have a small cooler on the return line of the stock cooler. The temperature on the return line reads max 140F, most of the time not even that. Everything on the serpentine belt system has been replaced. AC Compressor, Power Steering Pump, Alternator, Idlers, Tensioner, the belt itself. When I go above 2000 RPMS, There is a noise which sounds like a really bad/worse serpentine belt, knowing the CVT is belt driven, I believe it could be that. It only does it when moving, I can hit the rev limiter in park and it will not do it. It also has a loud "whine" when letting off the gas and will go away when I hit the gas again. That noise has been documented a lot from others, but not the belt noise. Anyone have any idea what this is?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Research Jeep cvt issues in Jeep forums. For whatever reason, CVTs are not as reliable as expected compared to conventional electronically controlled xmissions.

Comment: aware of the reliability issues, doesn't help me in any way though. They aren't as reliable because of the 'constant' part of it. They wear quick